# Why doesn't this custom linked list store every element given in c++?

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

I've spend a couple of hours solving this, but i think it would be better if someone could help me with it:

```
struct node{
    int x;
    node *next;
}; // basic node struct

class LinkedList{
private:
    node *head;
public:
    LinkedList(int init){ // initalizating the list 
        head = new node;
        node *rot = new node;
        rot->next = 0;
        rot->x = init;
        head->x = -1;
        head->next = rot;
        cout << "added:  " << head->next->x << endl;
    }

    void add(int adds){
        if(head != 0) {
            while ( head->next){ // goes to the latest head
                head = head->next;
            }
        }
        node *rot = new node;
        rot->next = 0;
        rot->x = adds;
        head->next = rot;
        cout << "added:  " << head->next->x << endl;
    }

    int push_last() { // pushes the last element, works fine 
        node *temp = head;
        while( temp->next)
            temp = temp->next;

        return temp->x;
    }

    int push_first(){ //shows the penultimate element instead of first one
        return head->x;
    }

};

int main()
{
  LinkedList lt(1);
  lt.add(2);
  lt.add(3);
  lt.add(4);
  cout << lt.push_first() << endl; // prints 3 / the penultimate element each time
  cout << lt.push_last() << endl; // prints last element always(4 in this case)
  return 0;
}
```

I do not want this to look like my homework, because it really isn't. I've tried to figure it out for a couple of hours changing it alot, thanks for any help!

Edit: rewritten it:

```
class LinkedList{
private:
    node *head;
public:
    LinkedList(int init){ head = new node;
    head->next = nullptr;
    head->x = init;
    }
    void add(int toadd){
        node *tnode = head;
        while(tnode->next!= nullptr){
            tnode = tnode->next;
        }
        tnode->next = new node;
        tnode->next->x = toadd;
        tnode->next->next = nullptr;
    }
    void print(){
        node *tmp = head;
        while(tmp->next!=nullptr){
            cout << tmp->x << endl;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        cout << tmp->x << endl;


    }
};

int main()
{
  LinkedList lt(1);
  lt.add(3);
  lt.add(62);
  lt.add(123);
  lt.add(9521);
  lt.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code using the debugger?

Comment: In the `add` function, are you really supposed to change where the member-variable `head` points`? That makes you lose the original head.

Comment: Note that `push` usually means **add** something to a container, so `push_first` is a peculiar name.

Comment: semi off topic: In `head = new node; node *rot = new node;` having `head` point to a dummy node that points to a real node is a bad idea. Just point `head` at the first node. Set head to `nullptr` if there is no first node.

Comment: @user4581301 setting head to nullptr hangs the process if i still want to point "rot" to head

Comment: @ptar If you're going to write your own linked list, the first thing you should have done is to draw boxes denoting the data and lines denoting the links to visually see what each operation will look like.  Then you take what you see on paper and implement it in code.  Trying to figure out how a linked list is supposed to work by coding it and hoping things just work out usually doesn't work out too well.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Why would you want to point `rot` at `head`? You have a singly linked list. semi off topic: `rot->next = 0;` there is no guarantee that NULL is 0. Convention recommends `rot->next = nullptr;` and testing against `nullptr`.

Comment: Are you intending 'add' to add to the front or back of the list?

Comment: @kfsone to the  back

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: that is exactly what I thought when I saw this: draw it on paper first.

Comment: @user4581301 have done that originally and changed it, not sure why. thank you.

Comment: @ptar -- Now how are you going to address the memory leaks (i.e. lack of destructor)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what about 
~LinkedList(){
        delete head;
}

Comment: @pitar That won't delete all the memory you allocated.  That is a separate issue altogether that you need to solve.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie free() the pointers after i'm done with using them?

Comment: Never use `free` to release memory allocated with `new`. Use `delete`, but you need to `delete` all of the `node`s you allocated. `delete head;` just deletes `head`. It does not delete the nodes `head` points at.

Answer (score 1):

In your add function, you move the head pointer to the last element, losing all previous elements (and leaking their memory).

You should use a temporary like you do in `push_last`

Comment: Have done a couple of changes and now it seem to work, edited post, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
void add(int adds){
    if(head != 0) {
        while ( head->next){ // goes to the latest head
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
    node *rot = new node;
    rot->next = 0;
    rot->x = adds;
    head->next = rot;
    cout << "added:  " << head->next->x << endl;
}
```

Here the problem is

```
    head->next = rot;
```

This *always* adds the new node at the front of the list, after head.

Since you indicated this is a learning exercise, he's a rework of your code with some hints. I added a destructor, decoupled the addition of nodes from the construction of the list but included a create-and-add ctor which demonstrates delegation of the two operations (creating the empty list and adding the first node), I added a `last_node` helper and an `empty` function.

I also renamed `push_first` and `push_last`: in reference to containers like this, `push` almost always indicates a movement, whereas your functions were simple *accessors*. I renamed then `front` and `back`, which is a convention used by the standard library.

I also moved the `Node` struct inside the LinkedList class and made it private (membership of a `class` is `private` by default, and `Node` is defined before the `public` accessor). If it *was* visible from outside, this would make it `LinkedList::Node`.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class LinkedList
{
    struct Node
    {
        int x;
        Node *next;
    };

    Node *head;

    // get a pointer to the last node in the list.
    // returns: head if the list is empty.
    Node* last_node()
    {
        Node* cur = head;
        while (cur->next)
            cur = cur->next;
        return cur;
    }

public:
    LinkedList()
        : head(new Node { -1, nullptr })
    {
    }

    // If you absolutely have to have a constructor that adds a node:
    LinkedList(int adds) : LinkedList()
    {
        add(adds);
    }

    ~LinkedList()  // destructor
    {
        // Free all of the nodes we created
        Node *next;
        for (Node* cur = head; cur != nullptr; cur = next) {
            next = cur->next;
            delete cur;
        }
    }

    void add(int adds)
    {
        Node* tail = last_node();
        tail->next = new Node { adds, nullptr };
        cout << "added:  " << tail->next->x << endl;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return (head->next == nullptr);
    }

    // returns: value of the last node (-1 if list is empty)
    int back()
    {
        return last_node()->x;
    }


    // Normal implementation requires caller to check !empty() first:

    // returns: value of the first non-head node
    // if the list is empty, undefined behavior.
    int front()
    {
        return head->next->x;
    }

    // alternatively:

    // returns: value of the first non-head node or -1 if the list is empty.
    int front_safe()
    {
        return (head->next) ? head->next->x : head->x;
    }
};

int main()
{
  LinkedList lt;
  lt.add(1);
  lt.add(2);
  lt.add(3);
  lt.add(4);
  cout << lt.front() << endl;
  cout << lt.back() << endl;
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/UzYCii

Rather than dealing with C++s legacy raw pointers, I would encourage you to next learn about `std::unique_ptr`: a standard library object that deals with ownership of pointers. When a `std::unique_ptr` goes out of scope it frees the memory (if any) that it points to, automatically. This includes when the `unique_ptr` is a member of an instance that is going away or being deleted.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: Thanks a lot! i'l take your advice and learn about those pointers, anything else you recommand besides that?

Comment: @pitar The standard library is a major part of modern C++, I would encourage you to familiarize yourself with classes such as `std::list`, `std::vector`, `std::array`. But writing your own implementations as a learning exercise can also be incredibly valuable - not just to understand how they work but to improve your understanding of the language and language and algorithm concepts.